# J-Meter, Load on server using POST REST API with HTTP call is working perfectly but missing few calls with HTTPS

Tags: post, https, jmeter, restful-url

i am using j-meter for load test of a server accessing REST api using POST Https. and it is returning following errors.

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection reset

or

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed

or

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect

though load test is successful with http call.

can any one help me to tell the exact issue? whether it is server side issue or client side?

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It might an issue with [IPv6 stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), try forcing JVM to use IPv4 addresses by adding the next line to *system.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

alternatively you can pass the above property via -D command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)

---

It might also be a case of using port below 1024 on Windows as non-administrator user, try configuring your application server to run on port above 1024 (default port for HTTPS is 443). Also double check that port 443 (or whatever) is not being used by anything else (for example [Skype likes to bind to port and 443](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows-desktop))

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for replying. i have un-commented the same line in system.properties by removing # from the start of the line. but i am still getting the same errors in response. port being used is 9443. one more thing. load test is working perfectly with 1000 simultaneous threads but it gives erroneous response when i run it with 1200 or greater.

Comment: Then it sounds like a bottleneck in your application, you can either report it "as is" or perform additional investigation. First of all check if there is enough headroom for your application to operate in terms of available CPU, RAM, Disk, Network capacity, etc. You can do it using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test). Then investigate further: double check infra components configuration, re-run your test with [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) telemetry etc

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by changing the SSL configuration in jmeter.properties file.
it was due to the mismatch of handshaking protocol at server and client side.
jmeter was set with all SSL flavors to handshake with server.
its the trick.

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution. I am also facing the same issue, could you please share exact solution like which line did you un comment or provided value in .properties file. # java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
#https.socket.protocols=SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1